# Fancybox 2.1.4 nav buttons blocking video in horizontal scrolling website

Tags: javascript, video, navigation, horizontal-scrolling, fancybox-2

I'm having trouble with the nav buttons blocking the video playback buttons on my website: http://kathyyuen.net/worksample.
I've the tested the settings on jsfiddle, and it works on there with a single mixed gallery: http://jsfiddle.net/kyuen3/STKUS/.

Not sure what the issue is. The only difference from the jsfiddle script and my site the implementation of the horizontal scrolling. It seems like the nav buttons moved but the click area is the same. I've tried to move the nav buttons further from the box and that doesn't work either. Does anyone have any ideas? I would really like to keep the horizontal scrolling format.

```
<head>

<!-- OVERRIDE LEFT/RIGHT BUTTON AREA -->
<style type="text/css">
.fancybox-nav {
     width: 50px;  
}
.fancybox-nav span {
    /* arrows will be permanently visible */
    visibility: visible; 
}
.fancybox-prev {
    /* Change to -50px */
        left: -50px; 
}   
.fancybox-next {
    /* Change to -50px */
        right: -50px; 
}
</style>


<script>
//horizantal scrolling website
$(function(){
    $("#page-wrap").wrapInner("<table cellspacing='30'><tr>");
    $(".post").wrap("<td></td>");
    $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
        event.preventDefault();
    });   
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({ 
      'onComplete' : function() {$("#fancybox-wrap").unbind('mousewheel.fb');},
      'transitionIn': 'none', 
      'transitionOut': 'none', 
      'titlePosition': 'inside', 
      'scrolling' : 'no',
 }); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page-wrap">
    <div class="post">
        <p> 
            <h2>Taxicab SoundMachine 2010</h2>
            <p>         
            </p>
            <img id="TSM" src="images/worksample/taxcabsoundmachine-1.png" height="400px"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

                $("#TSM").click(function() {

                  $.fancybox.open([
                      {
                          href : 'images/worksample/taxcabsoundmachine-1.png',                
                          title : 'mixed media'
                      },
                      {
                          href : 'images/worksample/taxcabsoundmachine-2.png',                
                          title : 'mixed media'
                      },
                      {
                          type: 'iframe',
                          href : 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/62499221?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;autoplay=1 width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen>',                           
                          title : 'Processing applet using themidibus library'
                      }
                  ], {
                      padding : 0
                  });

                  return false;

              });
            </script>

        </p> 
    </div>
    .....
 </div>
```

Comment: Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No.6

Comment: ended up having to override the width of the nav buttons `.fancybox-prev {left: -50px; width:50px;} 
.fancybox-next {right: -50px; width: 50px;}`